# importing more than one module while making .py file executable

Tags: python, module, hook, exe, pyinstaller

I need to import more than two modules **_utils** and **typedefs** while making my python script executable. For one module I am adding '**--hidden-import=modulename**' at the end of pyinstaller script. But for two column I came to know hooks are useful. But I am unable to figure out where should I store my hook file. Also what  should be my command to execute.
I am new to python, can somebody help me explaining it properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly create a pyinstaller hook, or maybe hidden import?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947639/how-to-properly-create-a-pyinstaller-hook-or-maybe-hidden-import)