# using python py2exe to convert to windows exe console

Tags: python, openpyxl

i am new to python, i found py2exe and used it on a small test python code and it worked fine.  i have now created a program that uses openpyxl library for excel spreadsheets. when i compile to .exe using py2exe i get no errors, however when i try and execute the new .exe i get the following in a log file and on console for my new .exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_to_excel.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\__init__.pyo", line 29, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\workbook\__init__.pyo", line 5, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.pyo", line 16, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\writer\write_only.pyo", line 23, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\writer\excel.pyo", line 36, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\packaging\extended.pyo", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name __version__
```

i checked c:\python27\lib\site-packages it contains "openpyxl" and "openpyxl-2.4.4-py2.7.egg"

i am not sure why i am getting the backtrace or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/633/compatibility-with-pyinstaller

I've not tried it, but try comment #2.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion, that lead me to --hidden-import from another post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947639/how-to-properly-create-a-pyinstaller-hook-or-maybe-hidden-import

so i used --hidden-import=openpyxl , i assume the link you gave me would work for having multiple modules you need to import :)