# PyInstaller runs fine but exe file errors: No module named, Failed to Execute Script

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

I am running the following code:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

`main.py` looks like:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(r'C:\Model\Utilities')
from import_pythonpkg import *

......
```

`import_pythonpkg.py` looks like:

```
from astroML.density_estimation import EmpiricalDistribution
import calendar
import collections
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict, defaultdict
import csv

....
```

By running the `pyinstaller` on `main.py`, `main.exe` file is created successfully.

But when I run `main.exe` it gives error with `astroML`. If I move `astroML` to `main.py` from `import_pythonpkg.py`, there is no error with `astroML`. Now I get error with `csv`.

i.e. if I change my `main.py` to look as:

```
import sys
from astroML.density_estimation import EmpiricalDistribution
import os
sys.path.append(r'C:\Model\Utilities')
from import_pythonpkg import *

......
```

The `astroML` error is no longer present when I run `main.exe`.

There is no error with `import calendar` line in `import_pythonpkg.py` at all.

I am not sure how to handle this random error with packages when running `main.exe` after `pyinstaller` run.

`import_pythonpkg` is located at `r'C:\Model\Utilities'`

Edit:

Error with `main.exe` looks as following even though the original `main.py` runs fine. Pyinstaller was even able to let me create the `main.exe` without error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Model\Utilities\import_pythonpkg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from astroML.density_estimation import EmpiricalDistribution
ImportError: No module named astroML.density_estimation
[29180] Failed to execute script main
```

Comment: do you have the exact error message?

Comment: pyinstaller may have run without error, but it may not be including the proper stuff. Are there any warnings? you can also post the log of the pyinstaller command so we have a full picture of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I believe PyInstaller is not seeing `import_pythonpkg`. In my experience, when adding to the path or dealing with external modules and dlls, PyInstaller will not go searching for that, you have to explicitly tell it to do so. It will compile down to an .exe properly because it just ignores it, but then won't run. Check to see if there are any warnings about missing packages or modules when you run your PyInstaller command.

But how to fix it...If indeed this is the issue (which I am not sure that it is) you can try 3 things:

1) move that package into your working directory and avoid using `sys.path.append`. Then compile with PyInstaller to so see if this works, then you know the issue is that pyinstaller is failing to find `import_pythonpkg`. You can stop there if this works.

2) explicitly tell PyInstaller to look there. You can use the `hidden-import` tag when compiling with PyInstaller to let it know (give it the full pathname).

```
--hidden-import=modulename
```

for more info, check here: [How to properly create a pyinstaller hook, or maybe hidden import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947639/how-to-properly-create-a-pyinstaller-hook-or-maybe-hidden-import)

3) If you use the spec file that PyInstaller creates, you can try adding a variable call `pathex` to tell PyInstaller to search there for things:

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\example_directory'],
    binaries=None,
    datas=None,
    hiddenimports=['path_to_import', 'path_to_second_import'],
    hookspath=None,
    runtime_hooks=None,
    excludes=None,
    cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
    cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,... )
coll = COLLECT(...)
```

for more information on spec files: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html

(notice you can also add hiddenimports here)

This answer may also prove helpful: [PyInstaller - no module named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/pyinstaller-no-module-named/41862192#41862192)

Answer (score 1):

It is about to module which loaeded on your computer. If your IDE is different from your environment, you have to load same modules on your device via pip. Check the modules on CMD screen and complete the missing modules.

Sometimes you must load the modules all IDEs on your device. In my case, there were two IDEs (pycharm and anaconda). I used pycharm but pyinstaller used anaconda's modules so i unistalled anaconda and tried again. now it works..