# How to make Pyinstaller 3.2 in Python 3.5 work with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` in my `python 3.5` script, when I convert my `.py` to `.exe` using `Pyinstaller` 3.2, I got this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: Path or glob "2100 10" not found or matches no files.
```

I ran into the same FileNotFoundError today when I tried to use PYINSTALLER to work with XLSXWRITER.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you give us any more information or code? It can't find "2100 10" but that doesn't mean a lot to us out of context of your code

Comment: Here is my sample script: # Print the last item from year and pop
year = [1940, 1960, 1980, 2000, 2020, 2040, 2060, 2080, 2100]
pop = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(year[-1])
print(pop[-1])

# Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a scatter plot: year on the x-axis, pop on the y-axis

plt.scatter(year, pop)
# Display the plot with plt.show()
plt.xlabel("YEAR")
plt.ylabel("POPULATION IN MILLIONS")
plt.title("WORLD POPULATION PROJECTION")
plt.show()

Comment: I used PYINSTALLER to convert .py to .exe without MATPLOTLIB is fine.

Comment: What is the full command you are using to compile with pyinstaller? Are there any warnings that are showing up when you run pyinstaller?

Comment: I have installed Anaconda3 4.2 (64-bit) and the command I used after the Anaconda Prompt is>>>  pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico mat_scatter.py. No warnings but the error message: "FileNotFoundError: Path or glob "2100
10" not found or matches no files."

Comment: Dear The4thiceman, When I ran a different code using PYINSTALLER and XLSXWRITTER, I got warnings: 

WARNING:  Removing import IPython.external.qt_loaders from module PyQt5.QtGui
 WARNING:   Removing import IPython.external.qt_loaders from module PyQt5.QtWidgets
 WARNING:   Removing import IPython.external.qt_loaders from module PyQt5.QtSvg
WARNING:   Removing import IPython.external.qt_loaders from module PyQt5
WARNING:   Removing import IPython.external.qt_loaders from module 
INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
WARNING:   Removing import IPython.core.pylabtools from module matplotlib

Comment: Here is the code without importing MATPLOTLIB but XLSXWRITTER : # 
import os, xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd 

cwd = os.getcwd()
infile1_data = pd.read_excel("excel_infile 1.xlsx", sheetname=0)
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(infile1_data)
rows=dataframe1.shape[0]  # find number of rows in dataframe
print(dataframe1)

infile2_data = pd.read_excel("excel_infile 2.xlsx", sheetname=0)
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(infile2_data)
i = 0
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('consolidated.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)
...
workbook.close()

Comment: # All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Program Files\Anaconda3:
#
matplotlib                2.1.0                    py35_0    conda-forge

Comment: First of all, you need to put your code and other pertinent information into the question yourself, it is really hard to read in the comment section. Second, There seems to be issues with PyInstaller finding the proper stuff. I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858417/pyinstaller-runs-fine-but-exe-file-errors-no-module-named-failed-to-execute-sc/46894037#46894037. It has to do with missing modules.

Comment: Other than that, I am not sure what is happening...

Comment: Dear The4thIceman, I will follow your advise in the answers you provided earlier. It is a similar issue. Thanks!!!