# Python 3.5.2 + PyQt5 to standalone exe

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I want to create a standalone `exe` containing `PyQt5`. I used `PyInstaller` and identified the folder where to find the `.dll` as follow:

```
pyinstaller --paths C:\...\Anaconda3\Library\bin --onefile --windowed test.py
```

The `exe` was created successfully and when I run the `exe`, the following error message appears:

[image]

FYI, my configuration is the following:

- `Anaconda3 4.2.0` with `Python 3.5.2` (by default `PyQt5` is installed via `Anaconda` so I never installed PyQt5 via a `pip install`. If I did that, a conflict appears and I can't use `PyQt5` anymore).
- `Qt 3.0.1`
- `.dll` used have not been found in the usual folder (i.e. C:......\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5) because I don't have a folder entitled "bin" in the folder `PyQt5`.

Thank you

Comment: were there any warnings when compiling with pyinstaller?

Comment: No warnings at all. Even if I do not specify the path where to find `dll`, Pyinstaller compiles the `exe` with no errors and this seems not normal to me.

Comment: if it isn't to large, can you update your question to show the output of your pyinstaller command

Comment: hmmm, tricky. give a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858417/pyinstaller-runs-fine-but-exe-file-errors-no-module-named-failed-to-execute-sc/46894037#46894037

Comment: otherwise there is something else going on here and I will need more information

Comment: I will have a look at your answer. I am not familiar with the output of `pyinstaller`. Did you notice an error?

Comment: What does your spec file look like?

Comment: I edited my post by adding the spec file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The PyQt5 installed by default with Anaconda seems corruptly in that particular situation. I uninstalled Anaconda and re-installed Python only and used pip install to install PyQt5. With this configuration, I was able to create my standalone exe.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that PyQt5 uses Qt5. You stated you have Qt3 in your environment, which doesn't make much sense.