# Is there a workaround for using Openpyxl with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I am getting errors when trying to freeze a script that imports openpyxl - and no .exe is generated.
The same errors if the script contains only 'import openpyxl'.

I am currently using Python 3.7.1, Pyinstaller 3.6, and Openpyxl 2.5.12. I freeze the script by copying it into the Anaconda scripts folder and then using powershell to summon pyinstaller to freeze the script into a single .exe. I have successfully frozen some other scripts using this method.

Searching for answers online showed that openpyxl doesn't like being frozen, but a number of places seemed to say that they had managed to find workarounds.

I have tried a number of the solutions suggested, including [placing the hook file in the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947639/how-to-properly-create-a-pyinstaller-hook-or-maybe-hidden-import) and calling it out as a hidden import in the powershell window:
`.\pyinstaller --hidden-import=openpyxl --onefile -w 'script.py'`

However, nothing I have found has worked. My script is rather large and I would prefer to not have to re-write it using a different excel module. Is there a way I can freeze my script to allow others to use it without having to install python?

Comment: please provide the errors if possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using cx_freeze it often gives less errors. Save the file names as given below and run the `build.bat` file

**setup.py**

```
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import * 

setup (
    name = "give_name",
    options = {'build_exe':{'packages': ['package_name']}},
    executables = [
        Executable(
            "give_name.py", 

        )

    ]

)
```

**build.bat**

```
py setup.py build
```

Comment: Is this definitely applicable to PyInstaller?

Comment: @Neil cx_freeze is not the same as pyinstaller. At the time of writing this answer, cx_freeze seemed to provide more control over how to package the python code.

Comment: Thanks. I had suspected info on cx_freeze might not be directly applicable to the question about PyInstaller. Good to know it's an alternative though.