# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x' because can't find the module folder, PyInstaller

Tags: python, module, compiler-errors, pyinstaller, exe

My code (test.py) looks like this (simplified):

`from app.utils import conversion`

`(code)`

When I try to make an executable using PyInstaller, the .exe works when I import generic modules. However, I get the following error message when I use ''from app.utils import conversion'' at the beginning of my code:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

and the .exe won't run.

My project is structured this way (simplified):

`project/app/test.py`

`project/app/utils/conversion.py`

The instruction I put in the console is:

`pyinstaller --onefile test.py`

Any idea why and how to overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly create a pyinstaller hook, or maybe hidden import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947639/how-to-properly-create-a-pyinstaller-hook-or-maybe-hidden-import)

Comment: Also https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed my problem:

in the `.spec file`, added the missing app module in `hiddenimports`:

`hiddenimports=["app"]`

Then to compile the executable, I run the .spec file instead or the .py file.

`pyinstaller --onefile test.spec`